# Can i restrict a user from making only one transaction in a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

For example in a voting dapp, I want only one address to make one vote. My doubt is can i store all the address of message senders in an array and check before casting the vote and hence allowing only one person to cast only one vote ?/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbounded array looping is bad and you can eventually exceed block gas limit once enough elements are in the array.

You should use a mapping.

```
mapping(address => bool) alreadyVoted;
```

Then in your contract you just flip the Boolean to true when they vote.

```
modifier notVoted() {
    require(!alreadyVoted[msg.sender]);
    _;
}

function vote(uint option) public notVoted() {
    alreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

You could have an array storing all addresses that already voted.

For example:

```
    address[] alreadyVoted;

    function vote() public returns (bool){
    //chekck if sender has already voted
    for (uint i = 0; i <= alreadyVoted.length; i++){
        if (alreadyVoted[i] == msg.sender){
            return false; // stop the function
        }
    }

    // do whatever you want with your vote

// store the sender address so that he won't be able to vote anymore
    alreadyVoted.push(msg.sender); //msg.sender is the address of the account making the transaction
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think a mapping may be more appropriate than an array in this instance. No looping required then.

Comment: What would be the value of your mapping? Also, it's easier to return an array than a mapping, if you want to get all the addresses that already voted.

Comment: `mapping (address => uint) public voters;

function vote() public returns (bool){
    
    if (voters[msg.sender] == 1){
        return false;
    }
    
    voters[msg.sender] = 1;

    return true;
    };`

Comment: Dear Andromelus,   when i use the code, it the remix browser throws away this error:   browser/Untitled6.sol:26:21: TypeError: Operator <= not compatible with types int256 and uint256
    for (int i = 0; i <= alreadyVoted.length; i++){
                    ^----------------------^

Comment: Hum, yes, but you store an integer that is useless.

Comment: @NoushadMohamed in the for loop, change int to uint

Comment: You should never loop thru an unbounded array in your contract. The reasoning is that the gas would rack up as more elements are pushed into the array, eventually to the point where you exceed block gas limit in your call.

Comment: Do you know a safer way to achieve this? This is the only one I can think about

Answer (score 0):

You seem to put an equal sign between address and user. But if you place this limitation (one address one vote), there is nothing stopping a user from creating multiple addresses and going around your enforcement. Identity management is an ongoing research subject in block chain and hopefully might assist you in this quest.